# Plug-in architecture, access to code in application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plugins

For a project I am doing, I want the Mac application to accept plug-ins. I like the whole idea of just adding Bundles to the application to extend it's functionality.

Only I came across a small question, where I can't find the answer to:

I need to include a JSON parser in my application, for some functionality. Is it possible for a plug-in Bundle to also use that same parser? Or does every plug-in that uses a JSON parser, need to include the parser themselves?

What is the best way to do this for separate Bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X there are two types of loadable things, a *dylib* and a *plugin*. (These two terms have specialized technical meaning in the context of mach-o, the binary format OS X uses.)

A loaded *dylib* can't refer to the libraries in the executable, while a loaded *plugin* can. As a side effect, a *dylib* can be loaded to any executable, but a *plugin* can only be loaded into the executable you specify when you make the plugin.

So you want to make a *plugin*. There is a template in the XCode to do that. Don't forget to specify the target executable in the linker flag, which can be set somewhere in the inspector.

For more, read [Code Loading Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html).

Comment: To share code between the plugins and your application, it's easiest to create a framework that contains that shared code and all required headers, then link the application to that framework, and link your plugins to it.  You can just embed the framework inside the application and tell plugin developers to get it from the application bundle when they develop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after reading some of the pro's and cons we decided to just use Bundles and let the plugins just supply their own stuff that they need. Thanks